# can we please do something about [patterns] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Suggest to

1. make [patterns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patterns) synonym of [design-patterns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns)
   <sup>because most of the questions in "patterns" tag currently fit</sup>
2. spin-off "pattern" questions that don't fall under "design patterns" into
   a dedicated tag  similar to [Stack Overflow 'pattern-matching'](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pattern-matching/info):

   > <sup>Testing whether a data structure has a particular shape or contains particular values in certain locations. Many functional languages provide pattern matching constructs. Most questions in this tag should also have the tag for the language you are programming in. Do not use this tag for regular expression questions, use [regex](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) instead...</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm hesitant to do a simple synonymizing. There are more types of patterns than design patterns. Architectural patterns, user interaction patterns, requirements patterns are all examples of other types of patterns that exist in software engineering. Although perhaps it would be easier to get rid of patterns first and then clean up design patterns appropriately.